# Icon changes if value changes

Tags: react-native

i have a like `icon` and `value` of `status` `0 or 1`.want to show `thumbs up` `icon` if `status` is `1` and `thumbs down` if `status` is `0`.and `toggle` the same when clicked

```
<View style={{marginTop:10}}><Icon  name={itemData.wliststatus===0?"thumbs-up":"thumbs-down"} size={16} type="font-awesome" onPress={() => this.navigateToApp(itemData)}/></View>
```

Fetched from `API`

```
itemdata:{
"userid": "1",
    "views": "258",
    "wliststatus": 0,
}

<View style={{marginTop:10}}><Icon  name={itemData.wliststatus===0?"thumbs-up":"thumbs-down"} size={16} type="font-awesome" onPress={() => this.navigateToApp(itemData)}/></View>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First create `state variable` that holds `whliststatus value` and create `function` that `toggle value` of `state variable`.

```
 state = { whliststatus = false }

const handlePress = itemData => this.setState({ whlistatus: !this.state.whlistatus }, () => { this.navigateToApp(itemData)} })


<View style={{marginTop:10}}><Icon  name={this.state.whliststatus ? "thumbs-up" : "thumbs-down"} size={16} type="font-awesome" onPress={this.handlePress(itemData)}/></View>
```

Comment: sir thanks for suggestion but onpress i have already a function,how to write tooglethumb funtion inside it..plz suggest as i am beginner in react native


 navigateToApp=async (data)=>{
        let user=await AsyncStorage.getItem("user")
        user=JSON.parse(user)
        some data fetched from API
           

  
      }

onPress={() => this.navigateToApp(itemData)}

Comment: it worked.thanks..how i can add toast for an ios device in react native

Comment: could you please accept the answer if it is working.

Answer (score 0):

Use [state](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/state) to change items dynamically.
First, in `state` variable, set your like status value as false.
Remember: the `state` variable will reside globally in your class

```javascript
state = {
    liked: false
};
```

Then in [componentDidMount](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html), after successfully fetching data, update your status accordingly in state:

```javascript
componentDidMount() {
    fetch(...)
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(res => {
        ...
        itemdata:{
            "userid": "1",
            "views": "258",
            "wliststatus": 0,
        }

        // here update "liked" status in state
        this.setState({ liked: itemdata.wliststatus == 0 ? true : false });
        ...
    })
    .catch(error => console.log(error));
}
```

Now, come directly to the render method, get or set the state and data will be handled automatically:

```javascript
render() {
    const { liked } = this.state;

    return (
        <View style={{marginTop:10}}>
            <Icon name={ liked ? "thumbs-up" : "thumbs-down" } 
            size={16} type="font-awesome" 
            onPress={() => this.navigateToApp()}/>
        </View>
    );
}
```

Then as it seems you might be updating the like in `this.navigateToApp` function. There in this method you can update your state as:

```javascript
navigateToApp() {
    const { liked } = this.state;

    ...

    // here just switch your liked status
    this.setState({ liked: !liked });

    ...
}
```